# How to trigger a function when this select box changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
<?php echo Form::select('order_item[quantity][]', $order_item->quantity,   
Util_Model::get_prop($order_item, 'item_sku', 'item', 'get_sales_restriction()') 
, array('class' => 'select-block check_quantity')); ?>
```

I have such a selectbox and the following code not work.

```
$(".check_quantity").change(function(){
    alert('come in');
    $.skus_check();
});
$.skus_check = function(){
    var item_skus_quantities = [];
    $('.check_quantity').each(function(){
        item_skus_quantities.push($(this).val());
    });
}
```

I want to get all the select values into an array.How to do it,thanks

```
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle clearfix btn-input" data-toggle="dropdown" 
 id="form_order_item[quantity][]"><span class="filter-option pull-left">1</span>    
&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button>
```

in fact the problem is because the bootstrap. in this span `filter-option pull-left`  is the selected value. How to deal with this?

Comment: you are using jQuery.. is your code placed INSIDE $(document).ready function? http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <script>
 $(function(){

    $(".check_quantity").on("change",function(){
      alert('come in');
     var ret= getChecked();
     });
 });

 function getChecked(){
  var items = [];
    $.each($('.check_quantity:checked'),function(){
     items.push($(this).val())
    });
   return items;
  }
 </script>
```